# Can I change ownership of the data directory content in a borg backup repo?

Tags: sudo, backup, ownership, borgbackup

I've been using borg-backup for the past few weeks (on Ubuntu 16.04).

Every time I need to mount a backup I've used sudo (`sudo borg mount ...`); if I don't, I end up with a permission error and the borg filesystem is not mounted.

The problem is that afterwards, the mounted filesystem requires sudo for everything. Since borgfs is read-only, I can't change the ownership with `sudo chown -R myuser borgfs-mountpoint` after the fact.

Because I can't do `sudo cd some-dir-inside-borgfs` with my normal user, I end up switching my user to root with `su` to navigate the filesystem and do everything else, which I'm not a big fan of (maybe this is OK? I'm still pretty new to *nix).

This is what I have inside my borg-repo:

```
myuser .
root   ..
myuser config
myuser data/
root   hints.314331
root   index.314331
myuser README
```

But everything inside the `data` directory is owned by `root`.

First: Is this normal? Is it this way in your borg repo?

Second: If I do `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser borg-repo/data/`, will my mounted borg filesystem be accessible by `myuser` the next time I mount it? Or is it better to not mess with the ownership of these files?

Comment: i think this ownership of the data/ directory is normal if you create any archives with `sudo borg create...` you'd probably have to test in a new repository with regards to changing the file permissions

Comment: No, I don't think that is normal. You should be able to do everything with your normal user. But the question doesn't include enough detail about your setup to pinpoint the problem.